# Is there a method to reset a react component using ES6 classes to its initial state?

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a game and when the game is over, I want it to reset to the initial state. I haven't found any meaningful information in the docs for this, so I've been playing around with adding a reset method to my Game class. First, I attempted doing the follow in hopes of creating a base class I could extend later, but using a variable for the component name fails:

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
    };
  }

  reset() {
    var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this),
        ComponentName = this.constructor.name;
    if (node) {
      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(node);
      ReactDOM.render(<ComponentName />, node);
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

I moved on, and tried to hardcode the component name as follows:

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
    };
  }

  reset() {
    var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    if (node) {
      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(node);
      ReactDOM.render(<Game />, node);
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

This works really well, but I am wondering if there is a built-in way that is better, or a more generic way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**
Please disregard the previous answer, replaceState is obviously not available in the ES2015 class pattern. Anyway, another solution is to keep an instance of the game in a wrapper component's state.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/upktozt1/1/

This will just remove the old game from App's state when you reset to a new game, and a new game will take its place.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.newGame = this.newGame.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      game: ()=><Game />
    };
  }

  newGame () {
    this.setState({
      game: () => <Game />
    });
  }

  render () {
    const ActiveGame = this.state.game;
    return (
      <div>
        <ActiveGame />
        <button onClick={this.newGame}>RESET GAME</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foo: 'Bar'
    };
    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  onButtonClick () {
    this.setState({
      somethingElse: 'Hello',
      foo: 'Changed foo'
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Set state.somethingElse</button>
        <p>state.foo: {this.state.foo}</p>
        <p>state.somethingElse: {this.state.somethingElse || '(not defined yet)'}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When using ES6 classes replaceState does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you need only reset `state` then you can move default state into some function or variable and when you need reset state only call `setState` with value from this function or variable.

Example:

```
class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.getState(); // set state from getState result
        this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.onReset = this.onReset.bind(this);
    }

    getState() {
        return {
            number: 0
        }
    }

    onReset() {
        this.setState(this.getState()) // set state from getState result
    }

    onButtonClick () {
        this.setState({
            number: this.state.number + 1
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>
                    Increment
                </button>
                <p>{this.state.number}</p>

                <button onClick={this.onReset}>
                    Reset
                </button>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eoumcvmL/)

Comment: That won't wipe out any new state properties that were added while the game is running, potentially causing issues.

Comment: @dannyjolie Yes, but better way is add all possible keys of state into default state than fully remount component.

Comment: Technically speaking; yes. But then you have to remember to keep the base state object in sync with the rest of the component. In the real world, you'll do some refactoring, add some new state attributes, etc in a few months, or even worse, another person will work on the code. No warnings will show if you forget to add the new state attributes to the base state, so for future proofness, just destroying the whole thing and creating a new game instance is a less error prone solution.

Comment: It's almost like setState needs to take a second parameter as boolean; if true replace state, if false or omitted setState as usual.  I am more inclined to agree with @dannyjolie just because it is much cleaner and 100% ensure that if somewhere something did break from best practices, it gets handled.

Answer (score 0):

I've just applied another solution to this problem using setState and iterating over the state's own properties, setting them to `undefined`, which is working nicely for me:

```
class Example extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this._handleInputChange = this._handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this._submitHandler = this._submitHandler.bind(this);
        this._resetHandler = this._resetHandler.bind(this);
        this._setInitialState = this._setInitialState.bind(this);
        this.state = this._setInitialState();
    }
    _resetHandler(){
        this.setState((prevState, props) => {
            var newState = {};
            for( var key in prevState ) {
                if ( prevState.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
                    newState[key] = undefined;
                }
            }
            if( typeof this._setInitialState === 'function' ){
                Object.assign(newState, this._setInitialState());
            }
            return newState;
        });
    }

    _setInitialState(){
            return {
                mode: 'advanced',
                created: {},
                changed: {}
            };
    }

    _handleInputChange(){
        // do stuff to change the state
    }
}
```

where _setInitialState returns whatever properties need to be initialized for the app to work.

This combines the advantages of not needing to maintain a full outline of your state in an initializer object, while also not requiring the overhead of re-mounting the component on reset.

Comment: another complicated workaround for a problem caused by bad architecture.